# Call SQL Stored Procedure from PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I need to call a stored procedure to insert the data to sql and it return a value with output parameter

like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertInfo
   @userid VARCHAR(100),
   @login_time DATETIME,
   @IsSuccuess BIT,
   @loginid INT OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Audit_LoginLogoutAttempt(UserID,Login_Time, IsSuccuess, DateCreated) VALUES (@userid,@login_time,@IsSuccuess, GETDATE())
      SET @loginid = @@IDENTITY
   END
   GO
```

How to send input and output parameters using PHP

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("{CALL InsertInfo(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $UserID);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $LoggedInDateTime);
  $stmt->bindParam(3, $IsSuccuess);
  $stmt->bindParam(4, $get_id, PDO::PARAM_INT, 32);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo $get_id;
```

I tried like this but I'm not getting desired value from $get_id

Answer (score 2):

You should [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) your parameter as an OUTPUT parameter. If you have output parameters in your stored procedure and stored procedure returns recordsets, you need to fetch all recordsets to get output values.

```
<?php

# Statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("{CALL InsertInfo(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $UserID);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $LoggedInDateTime);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $IsSuccuess);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $get_id, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);
$stmt->execute();

# Fetch results. Include this if your procedure returns resultsets (usually from SELECT statements):
#do {
#   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
#       // 
#   }
#} while ($stmt->nextRowset());


# Get OUTPUT parameter value
echo $get_id;

?>
```

I usually put [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as first line in stored procedures. This prevents SQL Server from passing the count of rows affected as part of the result set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertInfo
   @userid VARCHAR(100),
   @login_time DATETIME,
   @IsSuccuess BIT,
   @loginid INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Audit_LoginLogoutAttempt(UserID,Login_Time, IsSuccuess, DateCreated) VALUES (@userid,@login_time,@IsSuccuess, GETDATE())
    SET @loginid = @@IDENTITY
END
```